# Confirmation emails not being sent

Tags: civievent, joomla, confirmation

Our event confirmation emails are not being sent. The PayPal payment is happening, but the Online Registration Confirmation is not happening. What have I forgotten to enable??? We are using CiviCRM ver 4.7.1. I don't know how to find the version of Joomla. Emails DO go out, but only to those who do not owe any money - who have not gone to PayPal. Those who have paid remain in the "Pending (incomplete transaction)" status. We are NOT using "Pay Later".

Comment: Is civicrm otherwise sending emails (for instance through contacts or mailings) or is that broken entirely? If it's broken, I'd look  to your email configuration, but if you are able to send emails but the events aren't, I'd look to your event configuration.

Comment: There are way too many possible answers to this question, we'll need more info.  Please include your CMS (Drupal/Joomla/Wordpress) and CiviCRM version.  Also, please go to CiviCRM's **Administer menu > System Settings > Outbound Email**.  Press "Save and Send Test Email" and let us know if THAT comes through.  Also please add a screenshot of that page.

Comment: Equally having this problem in Joomla but older version 4.7.13. Set up brand new event, enabled Confirmation Emails and worked for five registrants. After that it causes the frontend Confirmation webpage to appear blank. There are no backtraces or web server logs that reflect anything to note.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently had to address this issue.

1) Make sure that the PayPal's "callback" setting is enabled and set to point to your website.

2) Speak with your sysadmin and make sure that calls from PayPal are not being blocked.

3) Look in your CiviCRM logs around the time of the payment to see if there are any errors.

4) Ask your friendly neighbourhood software developer (or me or a CiviCRM partner agency if you don't have one) to add extra logging and debug output to determine if the calls are being received and traced through the system.

5) Check the spam folders - there's a lot of things that you can do if emails end up being sent to spam.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for these thoughts. I have passed them along to my IT person.

Comment: Nice. Don't forget to answer Jon G and Naomi's questions above, and mark this question as answered!

Comment: The problem is not yet solved. I will post a note when that happens. Thank you to Jon and Naomi.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced a similar issue when for some reason, my hosting environment reverts to an older PHP version (5.3.29).  I use SparkPost and it needs 5.4.x so it stops working until I change PHP version.  Not sure if it applies to your situation but thought I'd mention.